# How to view the command that was just un(re)done

Tags: undo-redo, command-history

Is it possible to see the sequence of key presses that are undone/redone when using u and Ctrl-r commands?

Comment: As I know  it's impossible. You can keep typing `u` or `C - r` till get what you want.